# Replace using vim - Replace a pattern [...] by a string

Tags: vim, regular-expression, replace

I have a file containing lines in below e.g. format -

```
[foo@host.com, bar@host.com], Payment processed - 23499, params = {'invoice':3243}
```

I only want the account numbers i.e. 23499. It's a number. Let's say it `<account>`. 
Its not a constant.

For that, I am trying to -

1. Remove `params ...`
2. Replace [...], from start of each line by whitespace

By `...` I mean any string. I have tried -

```
# 1
:%s/params.*//g
# 2
:%s/\<[]\>//g
:%s/\<\[\]\>//g
:%s/\<[.*]\>//g
:%s/\<\[.*\]\>//g
```

All the things I have tried in `# 2` have not worked. What am I doing wrong? How do I get `<account>`? Help me out.

Comment: It seems that there has been serious confusion for what you actually want the output to be. Given the example input you mention, what would your desired output look like?

Comment: Coul it be that there is a comma missing in "2."? I had read "from start of each line by whitespace" as something with a whitespace separator. But with a comma, it's pretty clear: "Replace [...], from start of each line, by whitespace."

Comment: 23499. 23500. 36754. 43266 and so on. Account numbers from email subject

Comment: And no whitespace in front of them?

Comment: Each number on newline. I couldn't type a newline in the comment :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use following sequence to only retain the account numbers *(cudo's to J.D.Mohr)*
*note the space after the r in the command*

```
:%norm $F,d$Bhv0r
```

This assumes that there's only one `,` after the number you want to retain

**Breakdown**

```
:     -> Enter command mode
%norm -> Applies a normal command to the entire file
$     -> Jump to end of line
F,    -> Find preceding ,
d$    -> Delete until end of line
B     -> Jump back a word
hv0   -> Go left one character and select until beginning of line
r     -> replace selected text with <space>
```

Comment: @HalosGhost - The idea is to type the entire sequence on the line and hit return.

Comment: This is close, but doesn't quite do what was asked for. They wanted whitespace in place of the junk at the beginning of the line. `:%norm $F,d$Bhv0r ` works for me (with an impotant space at the end there).

Comment: @J.D.Mohr - I missed that, tx for the correction.

Comment: Yes i am able to remove [emails]. But the solution seems little difficult. Whats wrong with the things i have tried in #2?

Comment: @HussainTamboli - You are not searching for anything in your first two regexes and the last two are greedy. Try `/\v^.{-}\d+` as regex and work from there. The `{-}`is not greedy as opposed to `*`. The `^` is to start from the beginning of the line and the `\d+` is a number followed by other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the `<account>` string

```
awk '{print $6}' file| sed 's/,//' >> newfile
```

For possible future usage of the main data, this could be useful

Comment: I imagine this could be done with `awk` alone. It certainly doesn't need the pipe from `cat`, at least.

Comment: @HalosGhost You're correct

Comment: I would prefer if i get the solution in vim

Answer (score 0):

If you would look for `<account>` (something like `<12345>`) and have have `<` and `>` only in `<account>`, as it looked like in the original version of the question, then this could work:

```
%s/\v.*(\<.*\>).*/\1/
```

It matches `<` and `>` with anything between - which is in a group,
and anything before and after in the line. That is replaced by just the group.

**Answering the updated question:**

If you do not have `<account>`, but a number in this place, with no `<` and `>`: this works in a similar way:

```
%s/\v.* - ([0-9]*), params =.*/\1/
```

It matches numbers, in a group to keep them. And it matches anything before that ends with " - ", and anything after that starts with `, params =`, both up to start or end of line.
So the expression matches the whole line, and is replaced by the matched group that contains the number.

It's using `\v` for "very magic" regular expressions see `:help /magic`.

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry I created a confusion. I don't have `<` and `>`. In fact `<account>` is a number.

Comment: Oh, you should edit the question!

Comment: But `, params = ` is actually `, params = `, and ` - ` is ` - `?

Comment: If I am able to remove emails it will be great (emails are put in `[]`). I will easily be able to get the account numbers.

Comment: The update in the second part of my answer should already output the number only.

Comment: I have tried `:%s/.*\-//g` as there is `-` before the accountId I can get the account numbers easily now. By the way the solution you gave `%s/\v.* - ([0-9]*), params =.*/\1/` is not working. It says **Pattern not found**

Comment: Ohh.. now I see what you mean regarding the spaces, I did not understand that line. Hmm... pattern not found when the whole line is the input, or after the `s/.*\-//g`? Anyway, not important, you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as it might be to want to use `vim` (or `sed` for this), `awk` is actually entirely capable of doing this type of matching and substitution all on its own:

```awk
$ awk '{ sub(/^.* - /, ""); sub(/,.*$/, ""); print $0 }' file
23499
```

The above matches everything (with `awk`'s built-in [`sub()` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)) from the beginning of the line to the hyphen and space before the account number and replaces it with the empty string `""`. Then, it matches everything from the comma to the end of the line and replaces it with the empty string. This should robustly (e.g., regardless of how many emails or what their formatting might be) remove everything but the account number.

If you have access to `gawk`, then you can use a simpler solution (only one function call needed):

```awk
$ gawk 'match($0, /^.* - ([0-9]+),.*$/, a) { print a[1] }' file
23499
```

---

Of course, the above solutions print the new data to `stdout`. If you wanted to save the new data for use later, all you would need to do is add `> newfile` to the end of the above command (note, that `>` overwrites; if you would prefer appending, you can use `>>`).

`awk` has many limitations of its own (for example, working with many files at the same time), so it's not always the best tool for this type of manipulation. However, it is quite good at what it does, so when your use-case lines up with its round-house, I'd strongly recommend using it.

In addition, the above solution requires no interactive interface (like `vim`) and no piping.

Comment: How can I replace emails by whitespace? Emails are put in `[]`

Comment: you see I can easily remove some part from the lines using `Visual mode`. `vim` is just a preference.

Comment: Ahh, I think I misread your question; you were wanting the all the leadup information to be padded with spaces, rather than completely removed? Do you want it padded with spaces equal to character count? Do you want the `[]` to remain?

Comment: No i want to remove emails and the [] brackets that contain those emails

Comment: I added another solution that uses two `sub()` calls; the first matches everything up to the closing `]` and the comma and space that follows and replaces it with the empty string. The second removes everything after the account field.

Comment: We might need another regex for number 23499. Account number is not a constant 23499. Let me try your solution.

Comment: These solutions do not rely on a length or value of the account field. The examples above just demonstrate the appearance to the output. That is, it should work fine on any account number.

Comment: The updated solution should match your needs in a fairly robust manner. All it assumes is that there is a `-` (surrounded by a space on either side) before the account number and a comma immediately following it.